# How can i get the same effect as justify-content: flex-start using flex box with ghost items?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, flexbox

I'm working on an application with node.js combined with angular.js, and I need get the same effect as `justify-content: flex-start` with `justify-content: space-between`.

I was thinking about genererating ghost items in the rows, but I don't know how to acheave this.

this is my style:

```
 md-content md-list
        display flex
        flex-direction row
        flex-wrap wrap
        justify-content space-between
        align-content flex-start
        align-items flex-start
        -webkit-flex-direction row
```

and this is the flex-box

```
<app-sidebar class="md-black-primary-default background">
<nav>
    <md-button layout="row" ng-repeat="(name, tab) in ::ctrl.tabs" id="nav-{{ tab.title }}" ng-click="ctrl.select(tab)" ng-class="{ selected: tab.selected }">
        <md-icon class="md-black-primary-default text" md-font-set="material-icons">{{ :: tab.icon }}</md-icon>
        <span flex>{{ :: tab.title }}</span>
    </md-button>
</nav>
```